# Como buscar en dos modelos al mismo tiempo

Tags: django, django-models

Tengo los siguientes modelos:

```
class Videos(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class TimelinePoints(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    videos_id = models.ForeignKey('Videos', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Videos_id')
    # ... Otros campos sin importancia
```

Quiero hacer una búsqueda trayendo todos los videos cuyo titulo contenga el string ingresado por el usuario, y todos los videos cuyos `TimelinePoint` contengan también dicho string en su campo description.

Hasta ahora lo estaba solucionando de la siguiente manera:

```
videos = Videos.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains = string_ingresado) | Q(timelinepoints__description__icontains = string_ingresado))
```

Pero después me di cuenta que mi aplicación necesita tener la lista de descripciones de los `TimelinePoints` matcheados, por lo que tuve que agregar esta consulta debajo:

```
timeline_points = TimelinePoints.objects.filter(description__icontains = string_ingresado).only('description')
```

Esto no me convence mucho ya que estoy haciendo un proceso costoso 2 veces. Entonces mi pregunta es:

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer lo que necesito sin necesidad de realizar la misma búsqueda dos veces?

Comment: Intenta con esto https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizás lo que encuentro menos costozo para solucionar el problema es hacer este queryset:

```
TimelinePoints.objects.filter(
    Q(descripcion__icontains=string) | Q(videos_id__title__icontains=string)
).select_related('videos_id')
```

Teniendo en cuenta que así estás haciendo una sola consulta a la base de datos, en la tabla timeline, estas consultado los timeline que en su descripción tenga el string, y los timeline que los videos tengan en el titulo el string, luego estas haciendo un select_related a la tabla de videos para que los traiga en la misma consulta, lo único es que pueden repetirse algunos campos, por lo que es importante pasar un `distinct()` espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por responder! Como podría obtener todos los videos desde ese QuerySet de TimelinePoints? Ya que la sentencia `videos = [timepoint.videos_id for timepoint in qs_timeLinePoints]` no me está resultando

Comment: Cuando dices no te está resultando, te sale algún error o algo por el estilo?

Comment: El problema esta cuando hago un merge con otro querySet `v1 | videos`. Pero despreocupate, eso es para otra pregunta! Gracias por responder, aceptada!